# Debugger turns off screen echoing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, terminal

When I use debugger or byebug in a Rails program to debug, it works, but often causes further input to not be displayed. This happens if a request times out for example. My workaround is to kill the server and enter "reset", but how could I prevent it happening?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is a bug in `byebug`, I've seen it too. So the best way to prevent it from happening seems fixing the bug. :)

Feel free to open a bug report detailing steps to reproduce: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues

Comment: Thanks for monitoring this @deivid. Replicable bug logged at https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/59